# Why is my Git repository so much larger than Mercurial version?

Tags: git, mercurial

I've converted a Mercurial repository to Git, using fast-export.  But the Git repository is huge: 18 GB for Git vs. 3.4 GB for Mercurial.  None of my cleanup steps have helped.

My Mercurial repository is dominated by one 65 MB file (Anki flashcards in SQLite format) that gets updated daily.  Its history has grown to be 2.9 GB, under .hg/store/data.

I was hoping Git might be able to compress the history a little better, but I have been unable to shrink the repository below 18 GB!

I have tried `git prune`, `git gc`, and others, to no avail.  I even tried zipping the .git folder, and it still came out to be exactly 18 GB.

Am I missing something?

**Update:** I tried Bazaar (bzr), and it compressed my repository to only 2.3 GB. Nice!

Comment: Have you tried `git gc --aggressive`?

Comment: I did try `git gc --aggressive`, but it died after some time with a memory error.  But by that time, the temporary pack file that it was creating had already exceeded 5 GB... it wasn't looking any better than `git gc` I had run previously.

Comment: I know you didn't choose my answer, but I still think you should experiment with storing an sqlite dump of the database instead of the database itself.  Most version control systems do better with stuff that looks like source code than stuff that looks like binary data, even if they do actually handle the binary data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the `git gc` is failing, try manually running a `git repack` and then `git gc`.

---

My observations with SVN, Git and Hg:

I have always observed that SVN and Hg repositories were much smaller than the corresponding git repositories. This is because each change to a file - text or binary, adds a new full object for it. In SVN, only the diff is added, even in the case of binaries and the binary diffing in SVN is very good as well.

But this is where the pack files come in, since they store only diff (delta) amongst similar objects and are even compressed. Even with packing, I have observed that Git repositories, depending on the kind of files and the amount of changes those files undergo, tend to be larger. This is something I have come to accept with Git and it is a compromise I am willing to take given how fast the various operation are with Git.

Comment: My experience between SVN and git is exactly the opposite. In the repositories I've compared, the git repo is something like 3-5 times smaller than the SVN one.

Comment: @ Ryan Stewart - Like I said, it is going to depend on the kind of files and the amount of changes. A repo with medium to large binaries which change often will be bigger in Git than in SVN, even when packed.

Comment: Thanks @manojlds..  It was disappointing to see Git take up so much more space, but I guess I have to accept it.  I'll keep this repository in Mercurial for now.  Maybe in the future, Git will be able to store this repository as efficiently as Mercurial.

Answer (score 9):

One reason could be that Mercurial has a very compact storage format that involves diffs, even for binaries. And since using diffs to re-create versions can be very time consuming, it will store a full snapshot as soon as the diffs+old original exceed the double the size of a full snapshot.

Personally, I would try storing a dump of your sqlite database instead of the database file itself and see where that gets you. It might be far more efficient.

I do not know what git's storage format is. But I'm guessing it does not involve diffs in the same way as Mercurial's does.

Comment: Git performs differential compression as well, followed by a pass of zlib over the pack.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm just disappointed that I haven't been able to comfortably switch this repository over to Git.

Comment: +1 for suggesting a sqlite dump rather than versioning the db itself. Git (and Mercurial too actually) is mainly intended to be a *source* control system, not a version control system for all sorts of data. Of course it can certainly handle anything you throw at it; it just might take up a ton of space.

Answer (score 0):

Running `git gc --aggressive` on a repository migrated from Mercurial worked for me. It reduced from 500 MB to 150 MB.